# Android WebView isn't scrollable

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

My Android `WebView` isn't scrollable.

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#87cefa"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I'm loading the Website with the normal `webview.loadUrl(url);` function and sometimes with the `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");` function, both of them display the page, but they are not scrollable

Init:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

Loading:

```
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            [either one of them or the other]
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Maybe add ScrollView to be its parent?

Comment: Put webView into a linear layout and set orientation to vertical, Scrolling will be enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView Scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253444/android-webview-scrollable)

Comment: None of them helped :(

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution for this, All you need is to put WebView definition in "

> layout/content_my.xml

" not in "activity_my.xml"

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And  inside the MyActivity.java

```
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Exactly what the answer should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `wrap_content` for your height. If your `WebView` has the same height as its content, then there's never anything to scroll as obviously the content all fits by definition (though given you're loading content dynamically this may not be *exactly* what's happening). Try setting the height to `match_parent` or a fixed value.

Comment: sounds logical, but also doesn't help, i still can't move it around

Answer (score 1):

I had some other elements in my relative layout, which I switched to invisible. This made my webview not scrollable. My solution was:

```
relativelayout.removeallchilds();
relativelayout.addchild(webview);
relativelayout.addchild(overlaybutton);
```

Comment: possibly you have to use:      `webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` and i also used `setContentView(webview);`

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a scrollview, remove that scrollview and your webview will start scrolling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this as a comment as I think this may be a duplicate, but I would look at this question:

[Android WebView Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253444/android-webview-scrollable)

Which provides a few calls which I believe will solve this issue.

Another issue:

Try changing your webview from "Wrap Content" to some specific height.  Then set the scrollables.

Try something like 300dp and go from there.

Comment: Didn't help, still the same result :(

Comment: Also see the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: makes sense, but i still can't scroll

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the Same Problem with webview. It was not scrolling even with the match_parent attribute and very simple code.

The problem is not in your xml file. Its in your Java file.
In java file of that activity Override onPause AND onResume methods and iclude this code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    browser.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    browser.onPause();
}
```

It is very important that you Pause your WebView AND then Resume it again.
Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: these require API level 11. i'm seeing this issue on API level 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my web view to scroll by adding

```
simpleWebView = findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);

//setting the webView client to a new webview client 
simpleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

//and Enabling JavaScript
simpleWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I would not advise Enabling JavaScript because Using setJavaScriptEnabled can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into your application and this just means if your web site is vulnerable malicious JavaScript can be returned to your users.

When the malicious code executes inside your users browser, the attacker can compromise their interaction with your application.

and I currently don't know any other way to enable JavaScript

Here's the full code I used below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And inside the MyActivity.java

```
simpleWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

simpleWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

simpleWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

simpleWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

add this line and it will start working

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Hope, this solves your problem?