# Webview isn't scrollable android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have some content at `relative layout`, and clickable `imageview` which hide/show `textview` with link and `relative layout` with content. I have such problem: when a person doesn't hide text and relative layout my `webview` below this content can be scrolled up and down easily, but when the person hide the content above `webview` can be scrolled only down and can't be scrolled up. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910405/android-webview-isnt-scrollable) question, but my `webview` match parent and it can't cause any problem I think. Maybe I have some problem in another place?

> Here is my `xml` template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/jobViewLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.SubtitleText"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/old_item">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/job_link"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/content_layout"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="54dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hide_content"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/content_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_up_arrow"
        android:contentDescription="hide btn" />

</RelativeLayout>


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3.5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:labelFor="@id/swipeContainer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <my_package.jobAGENT.adapters.LollipopFixedWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:labelFor="@id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using that `<de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.jobAGENT.adapters.LollipopFixedWebView/>`

use `WebView` instead and it will work fine

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: because this is custom webview client which supports android 5.0