# window.scroll event does't work on android web view

Tags: javascript, android, scroll, android-webview

I've created a web view recently & everything seems to be working fine except the window.scroll event. I'm loading content in my mobile website once user reaches the end of the screen, unfortunately that doesn't work in Android Webview.

I've enabled javascript in Android Webview.

Here is the simple code I'm using in PHP:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  alert('H'); //This never happens
});
```

In main_activity.java, this line is included:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

What could be the possible reason behind this? Any solution?

Comment: Have you added the jQuery lib?
If yes, is the jQuery loaded before your js file?
If yes, could you attach the screenshot of your console of the Web Developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Yes it's added & before my js file

Comment: As this is Android Webview, I've not yet set up dev tools for an App. For a mobile website, this works perfectly fine

Comment: Please check this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253444/android-webview-scrollable
Make sure you enable the scrollbar in WebView.

Comment: That's not the thing I think. And that didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

make sure jQuery loaded finish, then your code can work fine
put the code after </html> :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            if (window.jQuery) {  
                // jQuery is loaded  
                alert("Yeah!");
            } else {
                // jQuery is not loaded
                alert("Doesn't Work");
            }
        }       
</script>
```

if alert "Yeah!", just replace alert("Yeah!") to your code.

Comment: Not getting any alerts, surprisingly.