# Incorrect width in Android webkit browser

Tags: android, html, webkit, width

I noticed a problem on Android's default browser, where 100% width may actually go past the edge of the screen. Here's a minimal test case:

```
  <div class='separator' width=100% style='border: 2px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class='separator' width=100% style='border: 2px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;'>New & improved div</div>
  <div class='separator' width=100% style='border: 2px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;'>another working one</div>
  <div class='separator' width=100% style='border: 2px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;'>another</div>
```

This works as expected on a desktop browser, but in Android webkit browser, the first div goes way off the screen, and doesn't change width when zooming in and out. The divs after it work correctly.

**Update**: I've tested this on 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, and a newly created 2.2 emulator, they all fail to size it correctly. It looks like other people have noticed this, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16287&can=1&q=100%25%20width&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12558&can=1&q=100%25%20width&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). Anyone know a good workaround for this bug?

Comment: What happens, when you remove `width=100%`?

Comment: It's exactly the same on Android browser without width=100%, maybe not needed? It displays correctly on all desktop browsers I tried, but not Android.

Comment: Changing width to 99% doesn't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: This example seems to work perfectly fine in 1.5 emulator, weird. Is this a bug introduced in 2.2?

Comment: Can you post your xml where WebView is declared?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem with the xml layout, it happens in the default webkit browser.

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem on Sumsang 2.3, and HTC 2.2. Can you post the whole html?

Comment: Just paste those four divs into a new .html file, try to zoom in on the mobile browser, and the first one will not resize correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my WebView, I was able to fix the widths by turning off wide viewport.

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

This disables horizontal scroll unless absolutely necessary, and div widths and zoom work as expected. Obviously this will only work with a custom WebView, maybe there is a more generic way to do this with something like <meta name="viewport" ...> ?

Answer (score 10):

Just add this meta tag inside  your html head tag .I've checked it with android 2.1 browser and it works fine on zoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: That seems to work well, but it doesn't let you zoom out as you normally could. At default zoom you can zoom in, but not zoom out.

Comment: praise to you. this thing took me a day and a night of trying until i found this.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
layout_width="fillparent"
```

:)

Comment: That may be helpful if the WebView were not taking up the full width, but that's not my problem. This is a problem with the HTML width, and it even happens in the default browser app.