# Android - fit page in WebView using pre-Eclair (2.1) version of OS

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I'm trying to load page into `WebView` control with best possible fit and ability to retain it when switching from portrait to landscape.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview/4322209#4322209) provides the acceptable solution however it only work in OS v2.1 and up. What would be equivalent to the `WebSettings#setLoadWithOverviewMode` method in older OS releases since it's only available from 2.1+?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting wide-viewport, or setting the  viewport tag to device-width, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460871/incorrect-width-in-android-webkit-browser)?