# Android disable webview input

Tags: android, webview, click, overriding, android-relativelayout

I have a layout that features a webview and various UI elements on top of the webview. This is a relativelayout.

Currently, no matter how many elements are visible on top of the webview, all scrolling will scroll the webview, it can still accept clicks and more. I want to conditionally disable these features of the webview

I am using `myWebview.setClickable(false)` but this seems to have no effect

insight appreciated

Comment: see if this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not confident about this, but perhaps forcing the WebView to drop its focus will do. Try `myWebview.clearFocus()`. Let me know if that worked or not. I'm not at my computer right now, otherwise I would know. :)

Comment: It did not work, I was able to disable input now with `mainContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
               public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                   return(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
               }
           });`  but now I am trying to disable that listener later on!

Comment: Hmm... try one of these two `myWebView.setEnabled(false)` and/or `myWebView.setOnTouchListener(null)`. I'm just trying to run down the list of possible disabling tactics. Good luck! :)

Comment: simply setting the listener to null worked for me! I kept reading that it wouldn't work