# Disable input controls in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a Webview in an Android App. Any type of content(pdf,png,doc) will be loaded in the Webview. I need to disable the input controls (checkbox, inputbox) in the Webview content. And If we use onTouchListener, the zooming controls should not work. Do anyone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it will help you

```
myWebview.clearFocus()
myWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Use the API 11+ calls to disable the controls
    // Use a seperate class to obtain 1.6 compatibility
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        myWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
      }
    }.run();
  }
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(null)
myWebview.setClickable(false)
myWebView.setEnabled(false)
```

Add the following property to webview inside your layout.xml file

```
android:clickable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

Checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754719/android-disable-webview-input) answer also.

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh. I will check and let you know.

Comment: hello @DayanaK have you got the solution?

Comment: hello @DayanaK update your webview in xml file as i have now update the answer please check updated answer and applied it and tell me it is worked or not?