# A Left to Right Wiggle in a WebView When it Should Fit to the Page

Tags: html, css, android-webview

After following all tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview) to disable scrolling nothing worked.

Why is it that my webview will shift ever so slightly to the left or right when it should just fit to the page without any horizontal scrolling?

*Left Image:*  Initial Load

*Right Image:* After swiping to the left.

[image] ... [image]

HTML:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body id="visitorinfo">
        <div class="visitor">
            <div class='titlebox'><img src="../images/helloworld.png"/></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#visitorinfo{
    max-width:500px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:16px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:5px;
}
.titlebox{
    float:center;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
.titlebox img{
    width:100%;
}
.visitor{
    margin-bottom:35px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:5px 10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

*Note:  This will happen with an image and also with text.  Also, I left out redundant "right swipe".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Causation:** From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp): "*The margin clears an area around an element (outside the border).*"  Therefore, since the `WebView`'s webpage filling area is `border` of the `body` tag and everything inside of it, adding padding around that causing the little extra left & right (and likely top & bottom) scrolling.

**To Fix:** Just remove the `#visitorinfo`'s `margin:5px;`.  You can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) why this will work.