# How to Disable Default Scrolling in WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

Whenever I open a website using **WebView**, the page is **already (initially) scrolled down**.

How to prevent this **default scrolling** by WebView?

Comment: Try this webView.setInitialScale(99);

Comment: please say functionality webView.setInitialScale(99); will it disable scrolling when i try to scroll?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview

Comment: Hi @JoeyEzekiel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview  this link says to disable scroll bar not scrolling

Comment: Ya Thakns @JoeyEzekiel i Got Answer Through this code public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) return true; else return false