# How to disable scrolling Vertical & Horizontal in WebView?

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I have found a similar accept answer in:
[Disable scrolling in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview)

Sample code is:

```
// disable scroll on touch
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

But the accept answer don't satisfy my requirements, because the video & audio progress bar's touch move event is also disable(embed in my WebView), so I can't drag the progress bar.

Isn't there another way to solve this? Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

Comment: there are further answers down in the same post - all failed ?

Comment: Thanks for you  reminding, and I tried all the way, finally i found two way on the bottom.^^

Answer (score 2):

I try all the way in this question: [Disable scrolling in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview)

And finally i found two way on the bottom:

---

The first one (answered by [GDanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474498/gdanger)): Extends `WebView` and override `overScrollBy()` method and `return false`.

```
public class NoScrollWebView extends WebView {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, 
                                int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, 
                                int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The second one (answered by [steelbytes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252871/steelbytes)): override onScrollChanged() method.

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    if (bAllowScroll) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    } else if (l! = 0 || t != 0) {
        super.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```