# Disable Webview scrolling and enable text selection

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I am having a `webview` showing an epub. I need to block scrolling.
I used below code but text selection not working.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      return true;
}
```

Actually i need text selection and disable scrolling.
How can i do that?

Comment: your code doesn't compile, right?

Comment: sorry corrected my code.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5274400/1516873

Comment: Thank you so much user1516873. Your suggesion helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
mTestWebView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
           Log.e("TTG","scrollX="+scrollX+" scrollY="+scrollY+" oldScrollX="+oldScrollX+" oldScrollY="+oldScrollX);
           mTestWebView.scrollBy(0,-scrollY);
       }
   });
```

Note: You need remove the onTouchListener first .

Comment: @Anilkumar Did this not work ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE); worked for me.