# Android WebView Read More

Tags: android, layout, expand

I'm trying to implement the "View More" like you see on most apps where they expand (with animation) the web view when the user clicks on the "View More" button, and collapses the web view when the user clicks on the button again.

I've tried : https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

But the layout doesn't is not able to wrap the web view because Android Studio puts out an error saying that it will produce bugs. And the link above doesn't expand and collapse at a certain height, it collapses the whole web view and expands the whole web view from the toppest point.

Can anyone provide a solution to this? I've seen this used in many apps that I've downloaded (mostly online shopping apps).

Answer (score 0):

You just need a combination of CSS and/or Javascript to achieve this and it better done in the website itself than in the Android app.

[Webview with read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356432/webview-with-read-more)