# How to hide scrollbar while scrolling webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, scrollbar

I want to hide scrollbar while scrolling in webview. I have tried the following but scrollbar still shows me whenever I scroll the webview.

I have tried the following code.

> android:scrollbars="none"

```
wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Try this wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

Comment: @NovoLucas The scrollbar is still showing as I scroll through it. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview