# Disable scroll view vertical scroll when webview horizontal scroll on going: android

Tags: java, android, webview, scrollview

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>
  <WebView/>
  <TextView/>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Disable ScrollView  vertical scroll when webview horizontal scroll on going.

ScrollView vertical scroll active when webview focus lost.

Currently when I scroll webview horizontally its scroll sticky.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview/9082507

Comment: @DipneshParakhiya Its disable scroll completely. I want horizontal scroll on webview as well.

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for answer. I try it, but I want when webview horizontal scroll ongoing at that time scrollview vertical scroll disable.

Comment: @BDC yes i have check that code and its working fine in my device

Comment: @BDC did u solved it?

Comment: @NileshRathod No.

Comment: @BDC did u try my below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50422216/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes, And It use full to webvew horizontal scroll smooth, but when I scroll horizontally on webview than sometimes vertical scroll of scrollview starts.